# Renumbering a set of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a table with data which looks something like the following:

```
# the columns #
url
title
group
id_within_group

http://www.google.com
google
search engine
1

http://www.yahoo.com
yahoo
search engine
2

http://www.bing.com
bing
search engine
3

http://www.facebook.com
facebook
social media
1

http://www.twitter.com
twitter
social media
2
```

if I do

```
select * from table1 where group = "search engine"
```

I will get

```
http://www.google.com
google
search engine
1

http://www.yahoo.com
yahoo
search engine
2

http://www.bing.com
bing
search engine
3
```

I would like to be able to delete any of these rows, but somehow get it to renumber the id_within_group.

SO if I delete the second one from the 3 above, it should automatically renumber then leaving me with

```
http://www.google.com
google
search engine
1

http://www.bing.com
bing
search engine
2
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Can you just use `ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by [group] order by id_within_group) as sequential_index` when you do the `SELECT` rather than actually renumbering?

Comment: Sounds interesting.  I'll try it out.

Comment: @Martin, it works!  Thanks.  Please add that solution as a standard answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My suggestion would be to do this in the `SELECT` if you just need to display a sequential integer.

```
SELECT   url             ,
         title           ,
         [group]         ,
         id_within_group ,
         ROW_NUMBER() over (partition BY [group] ORDER BY id_within_group) AS sequential_index
FROM     YourTable
```